# Firebase: how to add another array to the existing array?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to update my database with another array when the user uploads an image.
So the old array has to stay and the new array has to be added

```
getDownloadURL(upload.snapshot.ref).then(async (url) => {
  setDoc(doc(firestore, 'images', uid), {
    images: [
      [{
          userId: uid,
          image: url,
          description: description,
          tags: selectedTags
      }]
    ]
  })
})
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C1EE.png

Comment: Most likely this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) will help.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`usersUid: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(ADD_YOUR_USER_ID_HERE)` works

For Firebase array update function read this doc:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array